# ActionScript 3 Snake

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Im trying to get a two player version of Snake running but i am having trouble getting the second snake to work, player 1 plays with w,a,s and d while player 2 uses the arrow keys. Player 1 with w,a,s and d is working player 2 with the arrows does not. Instead the arrow keys control player 1 as well as w,a,s and d.I think it has to do with the onEnterFrame function but i've been starring at it for days and i cannot see anything. Im fairly new to ActionScript as well so some hints to point me in the right direction is all i need, Thanks!

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.Event; //used for ENTER_FRAME event

    public class Main extends MovieClip{
        const speed:int = 5;//speed of the snake
        var vx:int;
        var vy:int;
        var gFood:Food;
        var gFood2:Food2;
        var head:SnakePart;
        var head2:SnakePart2;
        var SnakeDirection:String;
        var Snake2Direction:String;
        var snake:Array;
        var snake2:Array;

        public function Main(){
            init();
        }
        function init():void {
            //Initialize everything!
            vx = 1; vy = 0;
            snake = new Array();
            snake2 = new Array();
            SnakeDirection = "";
            Snake2Direction = "";
            //add food to the stage
            addFood();
            addFood2();
            //add snakes head to the stage
            head = new SnakePart();
            head.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            head.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            snake.push(head);
            addChild(head);

            head2 = new SnakePart2();
            head2.x = stage.stageWidth/14;
            head2.y = stage.stageHeight/25;
            snake2.push(head2);
            addChild(head2);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , onKeyUp);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , onKeyDown);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnterFrame);
            //ENTER_FRAME listener is attached to main class and not to the stage directly
        }
        //This function will add food to the stage
        function addFood():void {
            gFood = new Food();
            gFood.x = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth-100);
            gFood.y = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-100);
            addChild(gFood);    

        }
        function addFood2():void {
            gFood2 = new Food2();
            gFood2.x = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth-100);
            gFood2.y = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-100);
            addChild(gFood2);   

        }
        //this function will reset the game
        function reset():void {
            removeChild(gFood);
            addFood();
            head.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            head.y = stage.stageHeight/2;

            vx = 1;vy = 0;

            removeChild(gFood2);
            addFood2();
            head.x = stage.stageWidth/4;
            head.y = stage.stageHeight/4;
            vx = 1;vy = 0;

            for(var i = snake.length-1;i>0;--i){
                removeChild(snake[i]);
                snake.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        function onKeyDown(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
           //handle player 1
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
            SnakeDirection = "a";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
            SnakeDirection = "d";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
            SnakeDirection = "w";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S) {
            SnakeDirection = "s";
        }
      //handle player 2
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
            Snake2Direction = "left";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
            Snake2Direction = "right";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
            Snake2Direction = "up";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
            Snake2Direction = "down";
        }
    }

        function onKeyUp(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
        //handle player 1
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A || event.keyCode == Keyboard.D || event.keyCode == Keyboard.W || event.keyCode == Keyboard.S) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }
        //handle player 2
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT ||event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
            Snake2Direction = "";
        }
    }

        function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
            //setting direction of velocity
            if(SnakeDirection == "a" && vx != 1) {
                vx = -1;
                vy = 0;
            }else if(SnakeDirection == "d" && vx != -1) {
                vx = 1;
                vy = 0;
            }else if(SnakeDirection == "w" && vy != 1) {
                vx = 0;
                vy = -1;
            }else if(SnakeDirection == "s" && vy != -1) {
                vx = 0;
                vy = 1;
            }

            //setting direction of velocity
            if(Snake2Direction == "left" && vx != 1) {
                vx = -1;
                vy = 0;
            }else if(Snake2Direction == "right" && vx != -1) {
                vx = 1;
                vy = 0;
            }else if(Snake2Direction == "up" && vy != 1) {
                vx = 0;
                vy = -1;
            }else if(Snake2Direction == "down" && vy != -1) {
                vx = 0;
                vy = 1;
            }

            //collison with stage
            if(head.x - head.width/2 <= 0){
                reset();
            }
            if(head.x + head.width/2 >= stage.stageWidth){
                reset();
            }
            if(head.y - head.height/2 <= 0){
                reset();
            }
            if(head.y + head.height/2 >= stage.stageHeight){
                reset();
            }

            //move body of the snake
            for(var i = snake.length-1;i>0;--i){
                snake[i].x = snake[i-1].x;
                snake[i].y = snake[i-1].y;
            }
            for(var i = snake2.length-1;i>0;--i){
                snake2[i].x = snake2[i-1].x;
                snake2[i].y = snake2[i-1].y;
            }
            //changing the position of snake's head
            head.x += vx*speed;
            head.y += vy*speed;
            //collision with tail
            for(var i = snake.length-1;i>=1;--i){
                if(snake[0].x == snake[i].x && snake[0].y == snake[i].y){
                    reset();
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(var i = snake2.length-1;i>=1;--i){
                if(snake2[0].x == snake2[i].x && snake2[0].y == snake2[i].y){
                    reset();
                    break;
                }
            }
            //collision with food player 1
            if(head.hitTestObject(gFood)){
                removeChild(gFood);
                addFood();
                var bodyPart = new SnakePart();
                bodyPart.x = snake[snake.length - 1].x;
                bodyPart.y = snake[snake.length - 1].y;
                snake.push(bodyPart);
                addChild(bodyPart);
            }
            if(head.hitTestObject(gFood2)){
                removeChild(gFood2);
                addFood2();
                var bodyPart = new SnakePart();
                bodyPart.x = snake[snake.length - 1].x;
                bodyPart.y = snake[snake.length - 1].y;
                snake.push(bodyPart);
                addChild(bodyPart);
            }

            //collision with food player 2
            if(head.hitTestObject(gFood)){
                removeChild(gFood);
                addFood();
                var bodyPart = new SnakePart2();
                bodyPart.x = snake2[snake2.length - 1].x;
                bodyPart.y = snake2[snake2.length - 1].y;
                snake2.push(bodyPart);
                addChild(bodyPart);
            }
            if(head.hitTestObject(gFood2)){
                removeChild(gFood2);
                addFood2();
                var bodyPart = new SnakePart2();
                bodyPart.x = snake2[snake2.length - 1].x;
                bodyPart.y = snake2[snake2.length - 1].y;
                snake2.push(bodyPart);
                addChild(bodyPart);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if my answer is helpful,please accept it by clicking on the tick at top left of my post.

Comment: Don't duplicate logic via copy and paste, write functions and better yet classes for reoccurring functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,let me explain your mistakes in this code:

1.You have the same `vx` and `vy` for both snakes !! this means both snakes should go parallel and to the same direction !!

2.and problem 1 won't happen because you set `head`.x and y but not `head2` for the other snake!

Just for being careless... :)

so:
1.add variables `vx2` and `vy2` for the poor second snake !

2.replace the second `setting direction of velocity` with this:

```
if(Snake2Direction == "left" && vx2 != 1) {
            vx2 = -1;
            vy2 = 0;
        }else if(Snake2Direction == "right" && vx2 != -1) {
            vx2 = 1;
            vy2 = 0;
        }else if(Snake2Direction == "up" && vy2 != 1) {
            vx2 = 0;
            vy2 = -1;
        }else if(Snake2Direction == "down" && vy2 != -1) {
            vx2 = 0;
            vy2 = 1;
        }
```

3.do anything you left for the second snake.(head2.x and y,collision for second snake, etc)

I  H☺P E  this helps !

Comment: Good I could help you.